# Retrieve .htaccess login name from PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication

`.htaccess` is a convenient way to filter accesses to a page, thanks to the Basic authentication for instance.

In this case the

```
  Require user chandler monica ross rachel
```

will authorize the access to the page to the 4 persons mentioned above (provided that they enter their appropriate password).

Is it possible in PHP to retrieve the login name that was entered by the user, after she logged in?

For instance *chandler* logs in and accesses `index.php`, is it possible to find out that  *chandler* is using the page from the index.php code?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php might be worth a look, though I'm not exactly sure that it's what you're after.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) if you are using **basic** authentication:

```
echo ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
```

Basic auth method is deprecated now, I sorongly encourage to  use **digest** authentication which is not more difficult. Instead of `htpasswd` you can use the `htdigest` binary. There is also an example for that on in the linked manual page.

Digest also uses the concept of **realm**. This is the same thing as `AuthName` you are already using but as basic auth only uses it to show to the user, digest also uses it for authentication purposes and saves it in password files.

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` might do the trick.

Comment: +1 thanks. Don't know who is the first... so chose the most informative answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Depends. eg. if your server's auth scheme is

```
AuthMySQL On
```

then the user name is in

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` seems to work with php 7.3.  One way to find out is to run a php script from within the protected folder.  Use `print_r($_SERVER)` and look at the results.  If you find the logged in name, you'll know which `$_SERVER` option is available.